# Where to add xml file for Questionform to mTurk

Tags: r, xml, mechanicalturk

I'm very new to using mTurk. I'm trying to create a pre-screener so I can accept or reject people based on certain demographic qualifications. Where does one upload the xml file containing the questionform? I've scoured the internet but can't seem to find any information as to where this file goes.

Comment: I see two r packages on CRAN that have the string "mturk" in them but neither of them is spelled "mTurk". You need to do a better job of explaining what is planned and you need to offer specifics about the programming task  about which you are asking for help. (This is a coding site.)